# limiting function as cost function: logistic function between -a and +a

Tags: optimization, constrained-optimization

I would like to fit a diffusion coefficient as function of e.g. salt, pH etc. If I use a linear combination of all variables, I will have to apply constraints because the model fails, if the diffusion coefficient will get too large or negative.

I was wondering if there exists a function that behaves similar to the logistic function (asymptotic between 0 and a certain limit) but instead it asymptotically reaches -1 and +1. In this way I would avoid constraints and bounds. At the same time, negative parameters would mean that the corresponding variables do decrease diffusion and vice versa.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Tangens Hyperbolicus behaves as you want.

[image: Tanh formula]

[image: Tanh Graph]